# Using React router link inside template string does not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, template-strings

I am trying to use Link  of react router inside a template string with no success.
i tried also to wrap the tag with ${} but that doesnt work either.

does anyone know how can i make it work?

```
  const getWorkFeed = () => {
    const tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
    firestore
      .collection("WorkFeed")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          tableBody.innerHTML += `<tr>
          <th scope="row">${doc.data().WorkType}</th>
          <td>${doc.data().Location}</td>
          <td>${doc.data().Date}</td>
          <td>${doc.data().WorkingHours}</td>
          <td>${doc.data().Payment}</td>
          <td>
          <Link
          to={{
            pathname:"/WorkPage/${doc.id}",
            docProps:${doc.id}
          }}
          className="btn btn-success btn-lg mr-2"
          role="button">
          Click
          </Link>
          </td>
        </tr>`;
        });
      });
    return tableBody;
  };
```

Comment: Any specific reason you're using `getElementById` instead of using a _proper_ React component? If you need to inject something inside an existing non-React HTML element you _could_ use a portal (see docs). Even in that case you do NOT build the HTML string but you inject the appropriate React components. The _best_ solution is (when possible) to use...React. Table body is a component and what you have here is its child component (and wrap `firestore.collection()...` inside `useEffect(() => {}, [])` to execute it once when mounting.

Comment: And to answer your direct question: this does not work because `<Link>` is not an HTML element but a React component. When injecting this code directly as HTML you completely bypass React then it won't ever render the `<Link>` component (React components stay in the virtual DOM, not in the HTML DOM)

Comment: hi adriano thanks for replying. this getWorkFeed function is in my contextAPI but it executes every mount :  useEffect(() => {
    const getFeed = () => {
      contextConsumer.getWorkFeed();
    };
    getFeed();
  }, []);

Comment: what i dont get is if Link is an react component and onClick is also react component why the second works fine?

Comment: Which second one?

Comment: the onClick one

Comment: I do not see any onClick handler in your code!